# .HTML files won't send with ftplib storebinary

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, cpython, ftplib

I am unable to use ftp.storebinary to send .HTML files. HTML files are the only files I have run into so far. I can send all other files I have tried including but not limited to, .txt, .js , .jpg, .bmp ...

Operating system and architecture: Windows 11, Python 3.9.7

```
    import ftplib
    ftp = ftplib.FTP("ftpupload.net") # FTP URL
    ftp.login("username", "password") # FTP ([Username],[Password])
    ftpPath = '/test/'
    ftp.cwd(ftpPath) # FTP directory

    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + 'index.html', 
    open(r'C:\Users\whybo\Desktop\index.html', 'rb'))
```

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: *"Unable"* is not very useful problem description.

Answer (score -1):

Transfering file using `ftp.storbinary()` can get issues if your `.html` file containing non-ASCII characters. Thus, your `.html` file might contain non-ASCII characters, which are harmful and prevent you from sending the file.

You can use `ftp.storlines()` method which operates on ASCII mode and it can handle files containing non-ASCII characters like `.html` files.

Last two lines of your code can be replaced by:

```
file_name = 'index.html'
with open(r'C:\Users\whybo\Desktop\index.html', 'rb') as f:
    ftp.storlines(f'STOR {file_name}')
ftp.quit()    # to close the ftp connection
```

Comment: The `FTP.storbinary` does not care about the file contents. It can transfer any file intact.

Comment: It seems like the FTP client has not been set to `Binary transfer type` yet. How do you think?

Answer (score -2):

My FTP provider will not allow me to install .HTML files outside of the designated location.. Problem Solved!

Comment: Is this due to your FTP client settings have not yet set to `Binary`?  Or is this due to your local firewall?

Comment: Not sure but when I upload files outside of the /htdocs folder in my remote FTP directory it uploads but then deletes. My FTP provider is my web host provider for my website files. Infinity Free hosting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).